# How to improve pandas indexing and setting value speed

Tags: pandas

I need to combine two large dataframes, which now takes hours. I wonder whether there is a faster way to do this.
Below is the example:
df1 contains some info about shirts, and df2 contains info about pants. I want to merge them into a new dataframe that shows all valid combinations. What is considered valid is that 'Size' and 'Gender' of shifts and pants should be the same while their color can defer.
And here is a simplified example (The real scenario is that both df1 and df2 can be 10k lines)

```
    import pandas as pd
    import itertools
    list_color = ['black','white']
    list_size =  ['S','M','L']
    list_gender = ['M','F']
    list_shirts_price = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
    lists_shirts = [list_color, list_size, list_gender]
    list_pants_price = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
    lists_pants = [list_color, list_size, list_gender]
    df_shirts = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(*lists_shirts)), columns=['Color', 'Size', 'Gender','Price'])
    df_shirts['Price'] = list_shirts_price
    df_pants = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(*lists_pants)), columns=['Color', 'Size', 'Gender','Price'])
    df_pants['Price'] = list_pants_price
```

df_shirts:

|  | Color | Size | Gender | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | black | S | M | 11 |
| 1 | black | S | F | 12 |
| 2 | black | L | M | 13 |
| 3 | black | L | F | 14 |
| 4 | white | S | M | 15 |
| 5 | white | S | F | 16 |
| 6 | white | L | M | 17 |
| 7 | white | L | F | 18 |

df_pants:

|  | Color | Size | Gender | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | black | S | M | 21 |
| 1 | black | S | F | 22 |
| 2 | black | L | M | 23 |
| 3 | black | L | F | 24 |
| 4 | white | S | M | 25 |
| 5 | white | S | F | 26 |
| 6 | white | L | M | 27 |
| 7 | white | L | F | 28 |

Then, rename make a copy of df_shirts and double the number of rows. And then rename the column names.

```
    df_combined = df_shirts.copy(deep=True)
    df_combined=pd.concat([df_combined]*2, ignore_index=True)
    df_combined=df_combined.rename(columns={"Color": "Color_shirts", "Price": "Price_shirts"})
Then, add two columns called "Price_pants" and "Color_pants":

    list_new_column_from_pants = ['Price_pants']
    for key in list_new_column_from_pants:
            df_combined[key]=''
    df_combined['Color_pants']=''
```

df_combined:

| Index | Color_shirts | Size | Gender | Price_shirts | Price_pants | Color_pants |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | black | S | M | 11 |  |  |
| 1 | black | S | F | 12 |  |  |
| 2 | black | L | M | 13 |  |  |
| 3 | black | L | F | 14 |  |  |
| 4 | white | S | M | 15 |  |  |
| 5 | white | S | F | 16 |  |  |
| 6 | white | L | M | 17 |  |  |
| 7 | white | L | F | 18 |  |  |
| 8 | black | S | M | 11 |  |  |
| 9 | black | S | F | 12 |  |  |
| 10 | black | L | M | 13 |  |  |
| 11 | black | L | F | 14 |  |  |
| 12 | white | S | M | 15 |  |  |
| 13 | white | S | F | 16 |  |  |
| 14 | white | L | M | 17 |  |  |
| 15 | white | L | F | 18 |  |  |

Then below is the loop to set the empty values:

```
    for key_size, group_size in df_combined.groupby(['Size']):
        for key_gender, group_gender in group_size.groupby(['Gender']):
            for key_color_shirts, group_color_shirts in group_gender.groupby(['Color_shirts']):
                i=0;
                for index, row in group_color_shirts.iterrows():
                    df_combined.loc[index,'Color_pants']=list_color[i]
                    for key in ["Price_pants"]:# in reality, this there are multiple loops for 'key'
                        key_pants = key.replace('_pants','')
                        df_combined.loc[index,key]=df_pants[key_pants][(df_pants['Size']==key_size)
                                                            & (df_pants['Gender']==key_gender)
                                                            & (df_pants['Color']==list_color[i])].tolist()[0]
                    i=i+1
```

And below is the desired output.

| Index | Color_shirts | Size | Gender | Price_shirts | Price_pants | Color_pants |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | black | S | M | 11 | 21 | black |
| 1 | black | S | F | 12 | 22 | black |
| 2 | black | L | M | 13 | 23 | black |
| 3 | black | L | F | 14 | 24 | black |
| 4 | white | S | M | 15 | 21 | black |
| 5 | white | S | F | 16 | 22 | black |
| 6 | white | L | M | 17 | 23 | black |
| 7 | white | L | F | 18 | 24 | black |
| 8 | black | S | M | 11 | 25 | white |
| 9 | black | S | F | 12 | 26 | white |
| 10 | black | L | M | 13 | 27 | white |
| 11 | black | L | F | 14 | 28 | white |
| 12 | white | S | M | 15 | 25 | white |
| 13 | white | S | F | 16 | 26 | white |
| 14 | white | L | M | 17 | 27 | white |
| 15 | white | L | F | 18 | 28 | white |

In reality, both df_shirt and df_pants are 10k lines. And there are also more columns to set. So the execution time is on the ordre of a few hours.

Comment: It's not clear to me which number you are referring to. Could you clarify the column name(and whether it is in df_shirts of df_pants or df_combined)?

Comment: They were typos (due to the table format here). I corrected that. Index does not matter. Order does not matter. Eventually, I will be searching df_combined with info like how much does a "black shirts+white pants+ small size+ for female" cost

Comment: Need to modify the columns "Price_shirts" and "Price_pants" so that there are different values and I dont want to create extra permutations for different "Price_shirts" or "Price_pants". I only want to create extra permutations for different combo of "Color_pants" and "Color_shirts". Once extra permutations are created and when two dfs are merged on columns "Size" and "Gender", then copy the "Price_shirts" and "Price_pants" columns.

Comment: Have you tried `df_combined = pd.merge(df_shirts, df_pants, on=['Size', 'Gender'], suffixes=('_shirts', '_pants'))`?

Comment: Surpsisingly, the outcome is what I need, although I could not understand it. The outcome is 16 rows. It has mixing of different colors of shirts and pants, but not different prices of shirts and pants. And in the combined, there is no differentiation between "Color" and "Price".

Comment: I would have tought the pd.merge would create 8*(2, due to permutation of colors)*(8, due to permutations of prices)=128 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid loop with `pandas`.

Input data:

```
>>> df_shirts
   Color Size Gender  Price
0  black    S      M     11
1  black    S      F     12
2  black    L      M     13
3  black    L      F     14
4  white    S      M     15
5  white    S      F     16
6  white    L      M     17
7  white    L      F     18

>>> df_pants
   Color Size Gender  Price
0  black    S      M     21
1  black    S      F     22
2  black    L      M     23
3  black    L      F     24
4  white    S      M     25
5  white    S      F     26
6  white    L      M     27
7  white    L      F     28
```

Use `pd.merge`:

```
out = pd.merge(df_shirts, df_pants, on=['Size', 'Gender'],
               suffixes=('_shirts', '_pants'))
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
   Color_shirts Size Gender  Price_shirts Color_pants  Price_pants
0         black    S      M            11       black           21
1         black    S      M            11       white           25
2         white    S      M            15       black           21
3         white    S      M            15       white           25
4         black    S      F            12       black           22
5         black    S      F            12       white           26
6         white    S      F            16       black           22
7         white    S      F            16       white           26
8         black    L      M            13       black           23
9         black    L      M            13       white           27
10        white    L      M            17       black           23
11        white    L      M            17       white           27
12        black    L      F            14       black           24
13        black    L      F            14       white           28
14        white    L      F            18       black           24
15        white    L      F            18       white           28
```

You set index to ('Size', 'Gender') for better filtering:

```
>>> out.set_index(['Size', 'Gender']).sort_index()
            Color_shirts  Price_shirts Color_pants  Price_pants
Size Gender
L    F             black            14       black           24
     F             black            14       white           28
     F             white            18       black           24
     F             white            18       white           28
     M             black            13       black           23
     M             black            13       white           27
     M             white            17       black           23
     M             white            17       white           27
S    F             black            12       black           22
     F             black            12       white           26
     F             white            16       black           22
     F             white            16       white           26
     M             black            11       black           21
     M             black            11       white           25
     M             white            15       black           21
     M             white            15       white           25
```

Comment: @John, I think this is not the fully solution as there is still remain the color problem. My question is if there are two or more shirts with (L, F, black) what is the correct price for the shirt?

Comment: In my scenario, (L,F) shirts must be paired with (L,F) pants, although the color of pants and shirts can be mixed, as long as they are both (L,F). Also, in my scenario, there is only one (L,F,black) shirt.

Comment: @John, My old answer was good but I updated to your sample.

Comment: I have marked the answer to be correct. However, I still can't understand why extra permutations were created for colors but not for prices.

Comment: @John... all permutations are there when joined on size and gender.  What prices are you missing?

Comment: I mean, extra permutations are created due to different combinations of pants and shirts, increasing the table size from 8 rows to 16 rows. So, although the result of the command is what I want out of this example, I was surprised to see that extra permutations were not created on different combinations of prices of pants and shirts, because the command itself does not distinguish between price and color. Before I see the outcome of the code, I would guess the outcome is either 8 rows of 8*2*8 rows, but not 8*2 rows.